# Developing an web directory search engine for enterprises information, what's better? use a database or files?

Tags: database, search, full-text-search, search-engine

I want to develop an web app for storing enterprises' information, so this info can be searched by keywords as by category, but principally by keywords, because the interface it's going to be as simple a Google. The doubt I have is, is it better to store this info in a database or in text files?

Answer (score 0):

If you want full text search, probably neither.  You should look into a search index such as Elasticsearch (http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/).  A search index stores data in a way that is optimized for searching.